# Irrelevant name "WooRank" shows in my website source code

Tags: magento, json-ld, rich-snippets

My website: http://idjewelry.com/1-75ct-7-stone-common-prong-diamond-band-in-14k-rose-gold-w3645-r-iadd.html

In source code it shows as

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Organization","name":"WooRank",
```

We have not given Woorank as name. I am unable to find where it comes from.

Any ideas to debug?

Comment: Your question is where this whole JSON-LD `script` is coming from? Or did you add it and you just wonder where the `name` property is coming from? -- And you are using a Magento site, right? Did you check your plugins?

Comment: thanks it's in other plugin code